# NotImplementedError: Cannot copy out of meta tensor; no data

Tags: python

```
base_model =  AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf',
    token=access_token,
    trust_remote_code=True,

    device_map="auto",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    offload_folder="offload/"
)
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(
    base_model,
    'FinGPT/fingpt-forecaster_dow30_llama2-7b_lora',
    token=access_token,
    offload_folder="offload/"
    
)
model = model.eval()
```

After running this model in google colab, I am encountering the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot copy out of meta tensor; no data!
```

Please try to resolve the error

I tried to change float16 to bfloat16 and float32 but still encountered the same error.

Answer (score 3):

By searching I found that:
GPU is the problem
This error is caused by Accelerate auto-offloading weights to either the CPU or disk because of insufficient memory on the GPU.

So on the g3.4xlarge (8GB VRAM, 122 GB memory) you'd run:
python inference/bot.py --model togethercomputer/Pythia-Chat-Base-7B -g 0:6 -r 120.
This will load up to 6 GB of the model onto the gpu and the rest into memory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, passing argument `device_map='auto'` wasn't reliable and causing the same error.

Solution, dynamically check if there's a GPU.

```py
def get_device_map() -> str:
    return 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

device = get_device_map()  # 'cpu'

base_model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path=huggingface_params.pretrained_model_name,
        load_in_8bit=False,
        device_map=device,  # HERE
        offload_folder=huggingface_params.offload_folder
)
base_model.config.save_pretrained(huggingface_params.offload_folder)
base_model.save_pretrained(huggingface_params.offload_folder)
```

```
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.56it/s]
```

This allowed me to successfully instantiate and offload the model:

```py
base_model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path=huggingface_params.offload_folder)
```

```
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6/6 [01:30<00:00, 15.08s/it]
```